# HTML/CSS acts differently if I move the div into it's own line in the code

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have the following HTML/CSS structure:

```css
.im-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.im-backdrop {
  background-color: var(--darkblack);
  opacity: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  outline: 0;
}

.im-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.im-container:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.im-wrapper .im-content {
  opacity: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgb(0 0 0 / 80%);
  min-width: 50%;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.im-image-holder .im-content {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.im-content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.im-figure {
  background: var(--black);
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.im-close {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 45px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 65%;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button.im-close {
  overflow: visible;
  background: 0 0;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.im-wrapper .im-content .im-figure .im-img {
  padding: 0;
}

img.im-img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.im-bottom-bar {
  max-height: 20%;
  background-color: var(--cyan);
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.im-title {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 18px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: var(--black);
}

.im-collapsed {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.im-left-bar {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.im-bottom-bar h2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--black);
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.im-bottom-bar .im-left-bar.im-collapsed .row>div {
  border-right: 1px solid var(--black);
}

.im-bottom-bar .im-left-bar.im-collapsed .row>div:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}

.im-bottom-bar .im-left-bar {
  padding: 10px;
}

.im-counter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="im-wrapper">
  <div class="im-container im-image-holder"><div class="im-content">
      <div class="im-figure">
        <button title="Close" type="button" class="im-close">×</button>
        <figure>
          <img class="im-img" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/185235465/photo/white-toast.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=3UrLtuMZhHW6AfLbpM-87W0pW2oQHKe7End6hfgG0g0=" style="max-height:1010px">
        </figure>
        <figcaption>
          <div class="im-bottom-bar">
            <div class="im-title">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 im-collapsed im-left-bar">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 text-left">
                      <h2>Credits</h2>
                      <div class="mb-1">stuff by waa</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 text-left">
                      <h2>Characters</h2>
                      <div class="mb-1">:3</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="im-counter"></div>
          </div>
        </figcaption>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the image content resizes along with the window. However, before I had the exact same code, but with the `<div class="im-content">` not in the same line as `<div class="im-container im-image-holder">`. If I do this, the image doesn't properly resize anymore and jumps down.

```css
.im-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.im-backdrop {
  background-color: var(--darkblack);
  opacity: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  outline: 0;
}

.im-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.im-container:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.im-wrapper .im-content {
  opacity: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgb(0 0 0 / 80%);
  min-width: 50%;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.im-image-holder .im-content {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.im-content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.im-figure {
  background: var(--black);
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.im-close {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 45px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 65%;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button.im-close {
  overflow: visible;
  background: 0 0;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.im-wrapper .im-content .im-figure .im-img {
  padding: 0;
}

img.im-img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.im-bottom-bar {
  max-height: 20%;
  background-color: var(--cyan);
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.im-title {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 18px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: var(--black);
}

.im-collapsed {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.im-left-bar {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.im-bottom-bar h2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--black);
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.im-bottom-bar .im-left-bar.im-collapsed .row>div {
  border-right: 1px solid var(--black);
}

.im-bottom-bar .im-left-bar.im-collapsed .row>div:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}

.im-bottom-bar .im-left-bar {
  padding: 10px;
}

.im-counter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="im-wrapper">
  <div class="im-container im-image-holder">
    <div class="im-content">
      <div class="im-figure">
        <button title="Close" type="button" class="im-close">×</button>
        <figure>
          <img class="im-img" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/185235465/photo/white-toast.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=3UrLtuMZhHW6AfLbpM-87W0pW2oQHKe7End6hfgG0g0=" style="max-height:1010px">
        </figure>
        <figcaption>
          <div class="im-bottom-bar">
            <div class="im-title">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 im-collapsed im-left-bar">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 text-left">
                      <h2>Credits</h2>
                      <div class="mb-1">stuff by waa</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 text-left">
                      <h2>Characters</h2>
                      <div class="mb-1">:3</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="im-counter"></div>
          </div>
        </figcaption>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made no other changes. I'm very confused by this behavior, as I believed that the formatting of which I write my code has no effect on the behavior, as long as I close the tags properly and such. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: You are correct that generally, formatting/whitespace of this kind does not make any difference in HTML.  I can reproduce your issue in the embedded StackOverflow "Run Code Snippet" windows, but not on my own machine in a separate browser tab.  Are you able to reproduce this problem outside of "Run Code Snippet", and if so, can you give some details on where/how you are reproducing it?  If it's specific to just "Run code Snippet", then I would hazard a guess at StackOverflow having a bug of some kind.

Comment: @Jake I am reproducing the issue on my browser when I have the code in a `.html` file and open it in Firefox. I also ran into the same issue when I was playing around with the code on JSFiddle the other day, so it definitely doesn't seem to be exclusive to StackOverflow. Very strange you're not running into the same behavior though...

Comment: @Yogi Thank you very much, that's exactly the kind of explenation I was hoping for! I didn't think it was some mysterious quirk, that's why I wanted to come here for an explenation :)
I just tested it out, too, and your solution works perfectly. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**pseudo-element causes layout problems**

*(I've converted my earlier comment to an answer at OP's invitation.)*

The problem is caused by this css rule that uses the [pseudo-element before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

```
.im-container:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The pseudo-element breaks the layout of the content div within the container. The problem is not obvious because the pseudo-element is invisible. It has a height, but no width. And how it affects the layout is influenced by the viewport size and whitespace between divs.

```
<div class="im-wrapper">
  <div class="im-container im-image-holder">
      <div class="im-content">
      
       content not shown

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The easiest solution is to remove the pseudo-element (via css) since it doesn't appear to be used for anything. Alternatively, one could also just remove the inline-block attribute to give the element some width.